# SVG support in QT designer

Tags: c++, qt

Is there anyway to get QT designer to show labels with svgs when laying out forms?  The svgs show up when I actually run the app but not in the designer.  Is there some sort of setting or plugin I have to tell it about?

I'm using it for designing .ui files only, the main project is a Visual Studio project.

Comment: I can see the .svg in Qt Designer.

Comment: Is this a specific problem with SVGs or does it happen with other image formats (e.g. `jpg`) as well?

Comment: just with svgs, png and jpgs show up just fine.

Comment: Must have been something with my QT install, I re-ran the installer and now it's working.  Thanks for verifying that it was supposed to work.